# Javascript not always working in Chrome Extension, when should I run it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have a Chrome Extension which is injecting both CSS and Javascript into the page, and while the CSS is always being injected, the Javascript is only working sometimes and not others. By not working, I assume it's running before the stuff exists that it has to deal with.

The Javascript is simply moving a `div` above another using `insertBefore` but this isn't always happening, and I assume it's because of when it's loading.

My manifest is currently:

```
{
  ...
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [ "*://example.com/*" ],
     "js": [
        "js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js", "js/myjavascript.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "css": [
        "css/mycss.css"
      ]
  }]
}
```

I have `run_at` set to `document_end` currently because it seemed to run smoother (when it does work), so I figure that's what needs to be changed.

If anybody has any suggestions, they're greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** A follow-up question regarding the answer to this question was added [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227689/waitforkeyelements-stop-a-script-firing-on-a-popup-in-chrome-extension), I felt it may be useful for others if I added it to this question.

Comment: Can't you use the jquery load `$(window).load(function(){ //Script });` So the content of the script will be run when the page loads.

Comment: He is injecting jQuery, he can use `$.ready` i bet

Comment: Both of these work but are making it noticeably slower (the page is loading and then you can see the div move), which is something I wish to avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the code is not always working, then that suggests that the element(s) are being created/loaded by the page's javascript.  So, you need to use standard AJAX-aware techniques to move that div.

The techniques are: timers, mutation observers, mutation events, and intercepting AJAX XHR (if applicable).  These are all discussed in other Stack Overflow questions, but: mutation events are deprecated/buggy; intercepting XHR gets messy and may not apply here; and mutation observers can get complicated.

I'd recommend downloading and adding [the waitForKeyElements() utility](https://gist.github.com/2625891) to your manifest.

Then the code to move that `<div>` becomes merely:

```
waitForKeyElements (
    "jQuery selector for div(s) you want to move",
    moveSelectDivs
);
function moveSelectDivs (jNode) {
    jNode.insertBefore ("APPROPRIATE JQUERY SELECTOR");
}
```

Keep your manifest set to [run at `document_end`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#run_at).  This is equivalent to `DOMContentLoaded` -- which is when `$(document).ready()` fires.  The default `run_at` fires too late and at unpredictable times. `run_at` `document_start` won't do any good, since: timers, mutation observers, etc. all will not fire until after the `DOMContentLoaded` event -- for current versions of Chrome anyway (Other browsers don't have the same limits).

---

---

## Alternate method, for the fastest action but slower webpage:

Regarding:

> (the page is loading and then you can see the div move), which is something I wish to avoid.

There are only two ways to do anything before `DOMContentLoaded` that work in Chrome:

1. You can set `mycss.css` to hide the div until after you've moved it.  This might be the most cost-effective method, performance wise.
2. Or, you can override `document.createElement()`.  This will respond to the new element as fast as possible (assuming it's created before `DOMContentLoaded`), but it might slow down the page overall, by a noticeable amount.

Set the content script to run at `document_start`, and the override code must be injected. So, the script would look like:

```
addJS_Node (null, null, scriptMain);

function scriptMain () {
    var _orig_createElement = document.createElement;

    document.createElement  = function (tag) {
        var element = _orig_createElement.call (document, tag);

        var movingNode      = document.querySelector ("MOVING DIV SELECTOR");
        if (movingNode) {
            var target      = document.querySelector ("TARGET DIV SELECTOR");
            if (target) {
                target.parentNode.insertBefore (movingNode, target);

                document.createElement = _orig_createElement;
            }
        }

        return element;
    };
}

function addJS_Node (text, s_URL, funcToRun) {
    var D                                   = document;
    var scriptNode                          = D.createElement ('script');
    scriptNode.type                         = "text/javascript";
    if (text)       scriptNode.textContent  = text;
    if (s_URL)      scriptNode.src          = s_URL;
    if (funcToRun)  scriptNode.textContent  = '(' + funcToRun.toString() + ')()';

    var targ = D.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
}
```

Do not try to use jQuery for this.

Comment: Your script (the first option) works great, however it's causing something which would be loaded inside small popup (on the same URL) with the same Selector to be moved onto the page behind it instead of leaving it where it is. Any ideas how I could fix that? - Obviously this isn't an issue on most of the pages, but the popup can be loaded on a page which doesn't contain the Selector and it then gets inserted onto the main page behind it.

Comment: Just missed the 5 min mark for edits: I used the `true` param, and this fixes the issue, but the "matches" then need to be reset when a URL changes or there's a scenario it could fail.

Comment: The thing to do is one or more of:  (a) Exclude the popup using the manifest, (b) Tune the selector passed to `waitForKeyElements`, (c) Check for the popup inside `moveSelectDivs`. ... We need more information to be more specific.  If necessary, start a new question and provide full details of the target pages and popups. Best to include a link to the target page(s).

Comment: I have now added a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227689/waitforkeyelements-stop-a-script-firing-on-a-popup-in-chrome-extension), I hope it's clear enough.