# waitForKeyElements(); - Stop a script firing on a popup in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

This question is a follow-on to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112730/javascript-not-always-working-in-chrome-extension-when-should-i-run-it) which needed asking and warranted a new post, so excuse me if I refer to things which may not be clear without reading the other question.

When using the utility [waitForKeyElements()](https://gist.github.com/2625891) I'm facing an issue in which a `div` is included inside a small popup contained within the same URL. My extension is currently running on the [Twitter](http://twitter.com/) site, and my intention is that a `div` contained on the profile pages (e.g. http://twitter.com/todayshow) gets moved above another `div` on the page. I'm doing this via `waitForKeyElements()` because of some loading issues which are resolved by using this utility.

However, on a profile page you can click a link to another users name which pops up a small window (inside the same window/tab, on the same URL) showing some info about them and a few previous tweets. The issue here is that the same `div` appears on this popup and is then moved to the main page behind the popup window, where it shouldn't be. On a profile page, this can be stopped by plugging in the `false` parameter to `waitForKeyElements()`, however on a non-profile page it is still possible to activate this popup which is then moving onto the main page, as the `div` I wish to move it above on a profile page still exists here, causing clear issues.

I'm wondering if there's a way around this, as [bugs in Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=100106) have stopped me from excluding these pages. So far (just brainstorming) I'm thinking:

- on a page where the `div` doesn't exist to begin with, create an empty one meaning `false` will handle the issue.
- somehow stop the script from firing on a given URL, although due to the way Twitter works this would have to monitor `OnClick()` and the page URL (I think) which I'm unsure how to do.
- stop running when the popup appears, but I have almost no idea where to start with that.

Any help is appreciated. Any necessary code related to this question can be found in the first two links, and the issue I'm facing can be seen by a quick visit to Twitter.

**EDIT:** When plugging in the `false` param it works when going directly to profiles via the URL bar, if you're on a profile and use a link to get to a profile, the script isn't inserted and my extension fails. So this would need resolving too, or an alternative method altogether.

Comment: `div.module.profile-card.component.profile-header` would be the easiest example to work with, as you can see what's happening to it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a brainwave that I could use `insertAfter()` to insert the `<div>` I was originally moving in front of, after the `<div>` I was originally moving. This `<div>` is not present on the popup, which means that nothing is moved onto the back page when it shouldn't be.

In regards to the previous question, my code is now simply:

```
waitForKeyElements (
    "jQuery selector for div(s) you want to move", // Opposite to what it was.
    moveSelectDivs
);

function moveSelectDivs (jNode) {
     jNode.insertAfter ("APPROPRIATE JQUERY SELECTOR"); // Again, the opposite.
}
```

This solves the issue I was having and my extension is now working just fine, however I will leave this question posted in case anybody comes back to it in future.

Comment: That'll work, if there is only ever one div of each type (movee and target).